# Should I use tf.add or + to add two tensors in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2.0 for Python 3.

Suppose I have two tensor variables, `x` and `y`, and I want to compute their element-wise sum `x + y`. Should I just write `x + y`, or `tf.add(x, y)`? If they are not equivalent, when should I use one or the other?

Comment: In my understanding they are equivalent and just performs `__add__` magic function.

Comment: @thushv89 If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my understanding they are equivalent and just executes the `__add__` magic function.